# Difference between _dbContext.Books.Remove(book) and _dbContext.Remove(book)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I see two different ways to remove a book:

```
_dbContext.Books.Remove(book)
```

and

```
_dbContext.Remove(book)
```

Why do both exist? When to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are doing the same - marks entity as deleted in `ChangeTracker`.

> Why do both exist?

It is difficult to answer why useful methods are exist. For example,
when using generic repository pattern it is useful to use `Remove` method from `DbSet`. For other cases it can be simpler to use DbContext's `Remove`.